# Why this base64 function stop working when increasing max length?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, base64, decode

I am using [this class](http://koders.com/cpp/fid0484833F12928E9E4B6973FAFFBB0376989ECABF.aspx) to encode/decode text to base64.
It works fine with MAX_LEN up to 512 but if I increase it to 1024 the decode function returns and empty var.

This is the function:

```
char* Base64::decode(char *src)
{
    unsigned six, dix;
    unsigned int d_len = MAX_LEN;

    memset(dst,'\0', MAX_LEN); 

    unsigned s_len = strlen(src);
    dix = 0;

    for (six = 0; six < s_len; six += 4)
    {
        unsigned long sr;
        unsigned ix;

        sr = 0;
        for (ix = 0; ix < 4; ++ix)
        {
            int sextet;

            if (six+ix >= s_len)
                return NULL;
            if ((sextet = tlu(*(src+six+ix))) < 0)
                break;
            sr <<= 6;
            sr |= (sextet & 0x3f);
        }

        switch (ix)
        {
            case 0: // end of data, no padding
                return 0;

            case 1: // can't happen
                return NULL;

            case 2: // 1 result byte 
                sr >>= 4;
                if (dix > d_len) return NULL;
                *(dst+dix) = (sr & 0xff);
                ++dix;
                break;
            case 3: // 2 result bytes 
                sr >>= 2;
                if (dix+1 > d_len) return NULL;
                *(dst+dix+1) = (sr & 0xff);
                sr >>= 8;
                *(dst+dix) = (sr & 0xff);
                dix += 2;
                break;
            case 4: // 3 result bytes 
                if (dix+2 > d_len) return NULL;
                *(dst+dix+2) = (sr & 0xff);
                sr >>= 8;
                *(dst+dix+1) = (sr & 0xff);
                sr >>= 8;
                *(dst+dix) = (sr & 0xff);
                dix += 3;
                break;
        }
    }

    return dst;
}
```

Why could be causing this?

Comment: The variable dst is not shown; neither is the decode function.  We need more information than this.

Comment: I don't know where dst is set, but with MAX_LENGTH < 512 it works fine but with 1024 doesn't. I dont undertand the function that's why I am posting it here.

Comment: dst is global; eeeeeeek!

Comment: This sounds like an outstanding situation to use to learn how to use a debugger.  Put a breakpoint at the top of that function, and step through the results, and see why it is breaking early.  Also, those are all terrible variable names.  `six = 0` I find particularly hard to swallow.  six can't possibly equal zero, that's what makes it six.

Comment: If I were you, I'd ignore this function and either find something else, or start over from the spec. This code seems to use at least one global (for no reason) and documents (lines 96-99) integer return values for a function that returns a pointer to char! When the comments disagree with the code, both are probably wrong.

Comment: @Dennis:if you look, it's fairly apparent that `six` is intended to mean "source index", not the number. Not good, but I've certainly seen a lot worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are `dst` is not sized correctly to hold all 1024 bytes. Without seeing `dst`'s declaration there is no way to be sure.